# doveadm sync -1: a simple case that's oddly hard

Tags: dovecot

I have two dovecot imap servers, and I have precisely *two* users I need to migrate.  *Once.*  I even have both of their passwords.  So this seems like it should be trivial, but I'm having trouble getting the options right so that it works.

The old host uses Maildir folders in home directories, so users authenticate as bob and sarah.  I *think* it uses TLS on 993.

The new host uses vmail, so users authenticate as bob@example.com and sarah@example.de.  I know it uses TLS on 993.

On the new host, I want to pull mail for users bob and sarah.  I try something like this, but no luck (and I'm many web searches and variations into this, just not the right ones).  Mostly, I'm searching for an example that makes clear to me some points I can't find on the man pages.

```
jeff@example.de $ sudo doveadm sync -1 -R \
-u bob@old-example.com -d tcps:bob@example.com:993
```

This give me the error `doveadm(bob@example.com): Error: User has no mail_replica in userdb.

I *could* just tar and rsync the mail from the old server to the new.  I'm not quite clear how to insert it into their vmail folder or if this is wise, although it's Maildir on both sides.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  If so, could you answer your own question.  I'm in exactly the same boat.

Comment: I did not.  One user did the transfer as a copy within her mail client.  For my own account, I used rsync, which led to some weird metadata problems that thunderbird saw and that mutt got right.  I never fully understood.

Comment: I think I found a work-around: I created a symlink.  That seems to have worked.